# How do I create a custom HTML layout/pattern from list data?

Tags: 2010

I'm very new to SharePoint as a platform and I can't work out how to output HTML in a format that I want. I have a list with the following data included in columns:

- Title
- Description
- Image URL
- Status

How can I get this data to display on a page within SharePoint 2010 so that it forms an expected layout from following a HTML pattern/template? Example:

```
<h1>{title}</h1>
<p class='introduction'>{description}</p>
<img src='{image url}' />
<span class='status'>{status}</span>
```

Note that the curly braces indicate the value displayed from the list.

The purpose of this is to have a user upload data into to a list, then the data is displayed in a more user friendly way. I have access to SharePoint Designer but would hope that a solution is possible via the browser, even if I need to copy to/from a code editor. There seems to be a way using client side scripting, which I'm not familiar with, but I would prefer the output is correct from the server side. I've also seen some mention of XSLT which I'm not afraid to learn if it helps me get what I need from the platform.

I've come from using other systems that do something along the lines of "loop over the following bit of HTML and output the values where specified", for example, WordPress.

If I'm not clear please let me know and I can provide more information. Perhaps due to my limited experience with SharePoint I'm not searching for the right questions on this site but I hope this isn't a duplicate question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use XsltListViewWebPart to achieve this. (In SharePoint 2013 we have an option to use JSLink). You can start sing the below resources.

http://maulikdhorajia.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-2010-customizing.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff806162(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks Suhail. Both those links were pretty useful and led me to https://paylord.wordpress.com/?s=xslt which has come in quite handy.