# How to create custom html page for displaying list information?

Tags: 2010, list, html

I am just learning SharePoint 2010 and have a question about creating custom web pages for displaying information. Here is my situation:

I have a list library that the user can filter to see only the relevant items they want. What I would like to do is have the user click on the title of a list item and have a new page come up that displays all the information about that list item in a nicely formatted html page.

As an example the out put for an item could look like:

```
<h1>{title}</h1>
<p class='desc'>{description}</p>
<img class="img-left" src='{image url}' />
<span class='status'>{status}</span> 
etc...
```

Where the information in the curly braces come from the selected list item. I have seen this [question on stack exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125241/how-do-i-create-a-custom-html-layout-pattern-from-list-data) but the solution offered is how to create a custom list view, not a custom page.

I have Googled high and low on how to accomplish this but haven't found a solution to this yet. If I was using Drupal or WordPress, this would be an easy thing to implement. there must be a way to accomplish this in SharePoint. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this:

1. Create a custom list definition and have your own HTML in the `dispform.aspx`
2. Create an application page, retrieve the item(you can retrieve the item using `SPQuery` or `Linq Query` based on the item id in the query string) using SharePoint object model and display the fields as you desire.